# How to databinding in ModelView and load data when tab is active only

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a tabbed page contains 2 tabs(Offices and Meetings)
here a short code of Booking.xaml

```
<?xml ..>
    <TabbedPage ..>
        <local:Offices />
        <local:Meetings />
    </TabbedPage>
```

and this c# code (Booking.xaml.cs)

```
        public partial class Booking : TabbedPage{
    
    private void TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               var _booking = BindingContext as LocalsViewModel;
    
                int index = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
                if (index == 0)
                {
                    
                }else if (index==1)
                 {
                 }
            }
    }
```

and this is my ModelView to fetch data to the offices and meetings lists

```
    public class LocalsViewModel
        {
            public List<string> ListsMeetings { get; set; }
            public List<string> ListsOffices { get; set; }
            public LocalsViewModel()
            {
                ListsMeetings = new List<string>();
                ListsOffices = new List<string>();
                BuildLocalList();
            }
            private void BuildLocalList()
            {
    // method for fetch the two listes with data
            }
```

and here the offices xaml

```
<?xml ..>
    <ContentPage ..    x:Name="_office" Title="Offices" >
                <ListView x:Name="_officeList"
ItemsSource="{Binding ListsOffices}"
                HasUnevenRows="true"
                RowHeight="-1">    
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            ......
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
</ContentPage >
```

the problem is there in row displayed in listview . but if i add BindingContext = new Local ViewModel() in offices.xaml.cs in the constructor it works but it call BuildLocalList twice and it influence performance

Comment: your VM should not directly access your View.  That is what datatbinding is for

Comment: thanks for ur answer, i understand , but the problem how to load data only when tab is active for better performance

Comment: use data binding to bind the ItemsSource of the ListView to the VM property

Comment: cant binding itemSource only when tab is loaded ?

Comment: you can only load the data when the tab is loaded, which is what you already appear to be doing

Comment: i faced a problem when doing (                if (index == 0)
                {
                    Offices office = new Offices();
                    office._officeList=_booking.ListsOffices ();//the problem here
                }
)

Comment: That is why I have suggested you use databinding instead of directly assigning the ItemsSource.

Comment: i used binding (<ListView x:Name="_officeList"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListsMeetings}") and it dosent work.

Comment: there is no public property "ListLocals' in your VM

Comment: sorry , yes i confused between varriable , i mean ListsMeetings , same problem , always empty listview

Comment: if your concern is about how to properly use data binding, then you should ask that question.  The question you did ask isn't really about data binding, and the code you posted doesn't demonstrate any attempt to use data binding

Comment: i understand , besides am newbie in xamarin and databiding , any solution to fix that please ? and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, bind your `ItemsSource` to your VM

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListsOffices}" ... />
```

in your VM, use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ListsOffices { get; set; }

public LocalsViewModel()
{
   ListsOffices = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}
```

then when you get new data, add it to the `ObservableCollection`

```
ListsOffices.Add(myNewData);
```

Comment: thanks for ur effort , but the same problem.. always no row displayed in listview

Comment: please edit your question to show the actual code you are using

Comment: thnaks ur solution solved my problem , i forgot to call VM in the constructor